# Cygwin mount -p returns blank

Tags: cygwin, mount

I run a script that gets the cygdrive prefix by running `mount -p`. Usually this returns:

```
$mount -p   
Prefix Type Flags

/cygdrive system binmode
```

Now the command returns the heading, but no cygdrive prefix, which looks like this:

```
$mount -p  
Prefix    Type   Flags
```

The system is currently running without exhibiting any other problems, but my  script is failing to determine the prefix. Where is this information stored, /etc/something?

Answer (score 0):

I dug through bash_history and found that someone (its is a shared system) ran "umount -c", which removes the cygdrive prefix. The solution was to run "mount -c /cygdrive". This added /cygdrive back when running "mount -p".